# An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request in OpenIddict

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, openiddict

So, I'm trying to implement OpenIddict version `1.0.0-beta2-0580` with `NET core 1.1` and I get the following error:

> `An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request`

This is based on this : https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/tree/dev/samples

[image: Connect rest call]

The db registers the database correctly, the settings is loaded and everything works here. The tables in the db: `__efmigrationshistory`, `aspnetroleclaims`, `aspnetroles`, `aspnetuserclaims`, `aspnetuserlogins`, `aspnetuserroles`, `aspnetusers`, `aspnetusertokens`, `basetransaction`, `openiddictapplications`, `openiddictauthorizations`, `openiddictscopes`, `openiddicttokens`

And then I have the following stack trace :

```
InvalidOperationException: The authentication ticket was rejected because the mandatory subject claim was missing.
AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server.OpenIdConnectServerHandler+<HandleSignInAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler+<SignInAsync>d__66.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Authentication.Internal.DefaultAuthenticationManager+<SignInAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.SignInResult+<ExecuteResultAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+<InvokeResultAsync>d__30.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>d__28.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+<InvokeNextResourceFilter>d__22.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+<InvokeAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware+<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.BrowserLinkMiddleware+<ExecuteWithFilter>d__7.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware+<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
```

In the startup I have :

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc();

    services.RegisterDatabase(aspNet: true, useOpenIddict : true);

    // Register the Identity services.
    service.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>(config => { config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = requireConfirmEmail; })
          .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DatabaseContext>()
          .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.AddOpenIddict(options =>
    {
        // Register the Entity Framework stores.
        options.AddEntityFrameworkCoreStores<DatabaseContext>();

        // Register the ASP.NET Core MVC binder used by OpenIddict.
        // Note: if you don't call this method, you won't be able to
        // bind OpenIdConnectRequest or OpenIdConnectResponse parameters.
        options.AddMvcBinders();

        // Enable the token endpoint.
        options.EnableTokenEndpoint("/connect/token");

        // Enable the password flow.
        options.AllowPasswordFlow();

        // During development, you can disable the HTTPS requirement.
        options.DisableHttpsRequirement();

        // Note: to use JWT access tokens instead of the default
        // encrypted format, the following lines are required:
        //
        // options.UseJsonWebTokens();
        // options.AddEphemeralSigningKey();
    });
}
```

And then at the configure I have this :

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IServiceProvider service, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseOpenIddict();

    // Create a new service scope to ensure the database context is correctly disposed when this methods returns.
    using (var scope = service.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
    {
        var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DatabaseContext>();

        await context.Database.MigrateAsync();

        OpenIddictApplicationManager<OpenIddictApplication> manager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<OpenIddictApplicationManager<OpenIddictApplication>>();

        // ---- Delete code comment ----------
        // To test this sample with Postman, use the following settings:
        //
        // * Authorization URL: http://localhost:54540/connect/authorize
        // * Access token URL: http://localhost:54540/connect/token
        // * Client ID: postman
        // * Client secret: [blank] (not used with public clients)
        // * Scope: openid email profile roles
        // * Grant type: authorization code
        // * Request access token locally: yes
        var client = await manager.FindByClientIdAsync("postman", cancellationToken); 

        if (client == null)
        {
            var application = new OpenIddictApplication
            {
                ClientId = "postman",
                DisplayName = "Postman",
            };
            await manager.CreateAsync(application, cancellationToken);
        }
    }


    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseBrowserLink();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    }

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

Then the auth controllers look like this:

```
public class AuthorizationController : Controller
{
    private readonly SignInManager<User> _signInManager;
    private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;

    public AuthorizationController(
        SignInManager<User> signInManager,
        UserManager<User> userManager)
    {
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    [HttpPost("~/connect/token"), Produces("application/json")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Exchange(OpenIdConnectRequest request)
    {
        Debug.Assert(request.IsTokenRequest(),
            "The OpenIddict binder for ASP.NET Core MVC is not registered. " +
            "Make sure services.AddOpenIddict().AddMvcBinders() is correctly called.");

        if (request.IsPasswordGrantType())
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(request.Username);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return BadRequest(new OpenIdConnectResponse
                {
                    Error = OpenIdConnectConstants.Errors.InvalidGrant,
                    ErrorDescription = "The username/password couple is invalid."
                });
            }

            // Ensure the user is allowed to sign in.
            if (!await _signInManager.CanSignInAsync(user))
            {
                return BadRequest(new OpenIdConnectResponse
                {
                    Error = OpenIdConnectConstants.Errors.InvalidGrant,
                    ErrorDescription = "The specified user is not allowed to sign in."
                });
            }

            // Reject the token request if two-factor authentication has been enabled by the user.
            if (_userManager.SupportsUserTwoFactor && await _userManager.GetTwoFactorEnabledAsync(user))
            {
                return BadRequest(new OpenIdConnectResponse
                {
                    Error = OpenIdConnectConstants.Errors.InvalidGrant,
                    ErrorDescription = "The specified user is not allowed to sign in."
                });
            }

            // Ensure the user is not already locked out.
            if (_userManager.SupportsUserLockout && await _userManager.IsLockedOutAsync(user))
            {
                return BadRequest(new OpenIdConnectResponse
                {
                    Error = OpenIdConnectConstants.Errors.InvalidGrant,
                    ErrorDescription = "The username/password couple is invalid."
                });
            }

            // Ensure the password is valid.
            if (!await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, request.Password))
            {
                if (_userManager.SupportsUserLockout)
                {
                    await _userManager.AccessFailedAsync(user);
                }

                return BadRequest(new OpenIdConnectResponse
                {
                    Error = OpenIdConnectConstants.Errors.InvalidGrant,
                    ErrorDescription = "The username/password couple is invalid."
                });
            }

            if (_userManager.SupportsUserLockout)
            {
                await _userManager.ResetAccessFailedCountAsync(user);
            }

            // Create a new authentication ticket.
            var ticket = await CreateTicketAsync(request, user);

            return SignIn(ticket.Principal, ticket.Properties, ticket.AuthenticationScheme);
        }

        return BadRequest(new OpenIdConnectResponse
        {
            Error = OpenIdConnectConstants.Errors.UnsupportedGrantType,
            ErrorDescription = "The specified grant type is not supported."
        });
    }

    private async Task<AuthenticationTicket> CreateTicketAsync(OpenIdConnectRequest request, User user)
    {
        // Create a new ClaimsPrincipal containing the claims that
        // will be used to create an id_token, a token or a code.
        var principal = await _signInManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(user);

        // Note: by default, claims are NOT automatically included in the access and identity tokens.
        // To allow OpenIddict to serialize them, you must attach them a destination, that specifies
        // whether they should be included in access tokens, in identity tokens or in both.

        foreach (var claim in principal.Claims)
        {
            // In this sample, every claim is serialized in both the access and the identity tokens.
            // In a real world application, you'd probably want to exclude confidential claims
            // or apply a claims policy based on the scopes requested by the client application.
            claim.SetDestinations(OpenIdConnectConstants.Destinations.AccessToken,
                                  OpenIdConnectConstants.Destinations.IdentityToken);
        }

        // Create a new authentication ticket holding the user identity.
        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(
            principal, new AuthenticationProperties(),
            OpenIdConnectServerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        // Set the list of scopes granted to the client application.
        // Note: the offline_access scope must be granted
        // to allow OpenIddict to return a refresh token.
        ticket.SetScopes(new[]
        {
            OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.OpenId,
            OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.Email,
            OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.Profile,
            OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.OfflineAccess,
            OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.Roles
        }.Intersect(request.GetScopes()));

        return ticket;
    }
}
```

The dependencies :

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="10.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenIddict" Version="1.0.0-beta2-0615" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenIddict.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.0.0-beta2-0615" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenIddict.Mvc" Version="1.0.0-beta2-0615" />

  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="1.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error you're seeing is caused by the fact your `ClaimsPrincipal` doesn't have the mandatory `sub` claim, as indicated by the exception message.

To fix that, you have two options: manually adding the `sub` claim or asking Identity to use `sub` as the name identifier claim.

**Add the `sub` claims to the principal returned by `await _signInManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(user);`...**

```
// Note: while ASP.NET Core Identity uses the legacy WS-Federation claims (exposed by the ClaimTypes class),
// OpenIddict uses the newer JWT claims defined by the OpenID Connect specification. To ensure the mandatory
// subject claim is correctly populated (and avoid an InvalidOperationException), it's manually added here.
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(principal.FindFirstValue(OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Subject)))
{
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Subject, await _userManager.GetUserIdAsync(user)));
}
```

**... or ask Identity to use `sub` as the name identifier claim:**

```
services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ClaimsIdentity.UserNameClaimType = Claims.Name;
    options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = Claims.Subject;
    options.ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType = Claims.Role;
});
```

Comment: A lack of `sub` claim was the cause in my case. 

Though, it was unexpected that the error originated in OpenIdDict's `ValidateSignInDemand` method rather than somewhere in the guts of `Microsoft.Identity`.

Answer (score 0):

InvalidOperationException: Could not create an instance of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader'. Model bound complex types must not be abstract or value types and must have a parameterless constructor. Record types must have a single primary constructor. Alternatively, give the 'reader' parameter a non-null default value.

Comment: This is just an error message, and doesn't appear to be an attempt to answer. Are you saying you tried one of the other answers, and got this error? Regardless, this shouldn't have been posted as an answer.

Answer (score -3):

open file startup.cs  and  Use the code below inside  ConfigureServices

`services.AddTransient();`

use model name into <>