# After updating ASP.NET Core 1.1 to ASP.NET Core 2.0 ,Return statement SignIn(ticket.Principal, ticket.AuthenticationScheme);is giving 500 error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, openiddict

I recently updated my project to ASP.NET core 2.0 from ASP.NET core 1.1 .I'm using **openiddict** for authentication.

This is my controller which is responsible for  request/response.

```
[HttpPost("token")]
public async Task<IActionResult> TokenAsync(OpenIdConnectRequest request)
{
    try
    {
        var ticket = await _service.ExchangeTokenAsync(request);

        return SignIn(ticket.Principal, ticket.Properties,ticket.AuthenticationScheme);;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(new OpenIdConnectResponse
        {
            Error = OpenIdConnectConstants.Errors.ServerError,
            ErrorDescription = ex.Message
        });
    }
}
```

this return statement

```
return SignIn(ticket.Principal, ticket.Properties,ticket.AuthenticationScheme);
```

is throwing 500 internal server error. The code works perfectly up-to this return statement but while executing this return statement getting 500 internal server error.

This is my Startup of file methods.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var connectionString = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:ApplicationDbContext"];

    services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql();

    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(
        opts =>
        {
            opts.UseNpgsql(connectionString, b => b.MigrationsAssembly("MenuSystem.Repository"));
            opts.UseOpenIddict();
        }
    );

    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    var validIssuer = Configuration["Token:Issuer"];
    services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidIssuer = validIssuer,
                IssuerSigningKey = securityKey,

                ValidateIssuer = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(validIssuer),
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateActor = false,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true
            };
        });

    services.AddOpenIddict(options =>
    {
        // Register the Entity Framework stores.
        options.AddEntityFrameworkCoreStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
        options.AddMvcBinders();
        options.EnableTokenEndpoint("/api/account/token");
        options.UseJsonWebTokens();
        options.AllowPasswordFlow();
        options.AllowCustomFlow("urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:facebook_access_token");
        options.AllowCustomFlow("urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:google_access_token");
        options.AllowCustomFlow("urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:microsoft_access_token");
        options.DisableHttpsRequirement();
        options.AddSigningKey(securityKey);

    });


    services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
    {
        // Password settings
        options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
        options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
        options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
        options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
        options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;

        // Lockout settings
        options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
        options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 10;

        // User settings
        options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
    });


    services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
    {
        builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader();
    }));

    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(new GlobalExceptionFilter());
    });   

    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public virtual void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Here is Debug Log

```
   info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.SignInResult[1]
Project>       Executing SignInResult with authentication scheme (ASOS) and the following principal: System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.
Project> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.SignInResult[1]
Project>       Executing SignInResult with authentication scheme (ASOS) and the following principal: System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.
Project> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
Project>       Executed action Project.Controllers.AccountController.TokenAsync (Project) in 15632.6224ms
Project> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
Project>       Executed action Project.Controllers.AccountController.TokenAsync (Project) in 15632.6224ms
Project> fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
Project>       Connection id "0HL852SU6TGOD", Request id "0HL852SU6TGOD:00000004": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
Project> System.InvalidOperationException: The authentication ticket was rejected because the mandatory subject claim was missing.
Project>    at AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server.OpenIdConnectServerHandler.<SignInAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
Project> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: It's not providing any information  about the exception just 500 internal server error.

Comment: Check your application logs.

Comment: Thank you found the answer with the help of log .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This answer is copied from original answer** https://stackoverflow.com/a/44845552

The error you're seeing is caused by the fact your `ClaimsPrincipal` doesn't have the mandatory `sub` claim, as indicated by the exception message

To fix that, you have two options: manually adding the `sub` claim or asking Identity to use `sub` as the name identifier claim

**Add the sub claims to the principal returned by** `await _signInManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(user);...`

```
// Note: while ASP.NET Core Identity uses the legacy WS-Federation claims (exposed by the ClaimTypes class),
// OpenIddict uses the newer JWT claims defined by the OpenID Connect specification. To ensure the mandatory
// subject claim is correctly populated (and avoid an InvalidOperationException), it's manually added here.
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(principal.FindFirstValue(OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Subject)))
{
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Subject, await _userManager.GetUserIdAsync(user)));
}
```

**... or ask Identity to use `sub` as the name identifier claim:**

```
   services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ClaimsIdentity.UserNameClaimType = OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Name;
    options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Subject;
    options.ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType = OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Role;
});
```